# No option to validate for email in drupal webforms validation

Tags: webforms, forms

I've installed both the [Clientside Validation](https://drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) module, and [Webform Validation](https://drupal.org/project/webform_validation), but there is no option to validate for **"valid email"** in the **"Form Validation"** tab of the webforms edit panel. Clientside Validation claims to validate for email - what's going on?

How should I go about adding email validation?

Comment: There should be an "email" webform component. It does not validate?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it seems there is no such functionality, as it still sits in issue queue as a feature request. You can either:

- Use [plugin from feature request](https://drupal.org/node/1131328), it's already there in issue queue.
- Use regex validator, with one of the rules you choose. Simplest "usually OK" would be `\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b` and you can find more at [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Comment: I checked my webform, it validate by itself, no need extra functionality (for example if i type wrong email like "dfgdfh"). can you please look in to this

Comment: @Bala maybe someone just forgot to update feature request's status, then?

Answer (score 1):

try with this code inside your form alter:

```
// Add a callback function to your email field.
$form['mail']['#ajax'] = array(
  'callback' => 'email_validation',
  'wrapper' => 'email_validation_message',
);

// Field-wrapper to display result message
$form['email_presence_message'] = array(
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#prefix' => '<div id="email_presence_message">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#weight' => -1,
);
```

The ajax callback:

```
/**
 * Ajax callback.
 */
function email_validation($form, $form_state) {

  if (!valid_email_address($form_state['values']['email'])) {
    form_set_error('email', t('That e-mail address is not valid.'));
    $form['email_presence_message']['#markup'] = t('email not valid');
    return $form['account']['email_presence_message'];

  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have been experinced the same problem since, the first version of my website was a real issues and bad design...
i found this, hopefully helps you... https://drupal.org/project/clientside_validation

Comment: just select, Regular expresion Case- insensitive on  form validation tab and add this regex.  ^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$   worked perfectly for me, because I had data and the email field was created as text not as E-mail..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [valid_email_address()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/valid_email_address/7) function to validate your email.

```
function MyModule_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    if (!valid_email_address($form_state['values']['email'])) {
        form_set_error('email', t('That e-mail address is not valid.'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Webform Validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation) module  and **use Regular expression, case-insensitive**.

Eg:

1. For name validation: `\b[A-Z]{3,30}\b`
2. For mobile number: `\b[0-9]{10,15}\b`

Now you can use any regular expression to validate your web form.

Answer (score 0):

Get [Email Verification](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_verify) module. Though it is still in development for durpal 7.0 it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

[Webform Validation](https://drupal.org/project/webform_validation)  with this module you can set validation rules for each fields see the below image.

> This module adds an extra tab to each webform node, allowing you to
>   specify validation rules for your webform components. You can create
>   one or more of the predefined validation rules, and select which
>   webform component(s) should be validated against those.

[image]

Comment: but OPs question is really "What's the proper validator for E-mail?"